# map an object return unresolved reference

Tags: android, transformation

I'm trying to map a network object to a domain object with a .map in the response, but compiler says me that .map is an unresolved reference. What is wrong?

```
suspend fun getAllPlayersFromNetwork(): PlayersDomainModel {
    val response: PlayersNetworkModel = api.getAllPlayers()
    **return response.**map** { it.toDomain() }**
}
```

This is the data class of the network part

```
data class PlayersNetworkModel(

    @SerializedName("data") var data: MutableList<DataNetworkModel> = mutableListOf(),
    @SerializedName("meta") var meta: MetaNetworkModel? = MetaNetworkModel()

){
    constructor() : this(mutableListOf(), MetaNetworkModel())
}
```

This is the object of the domain

```
data class PlayersDomainModel(

    var data: MutableList<DataDomainModel> = mutableListOf(),
    var meta: MetaDomainModel? = MetaDomainModel()

)
```

and this is the transform method to map

```
fun PlayersNetworkModel.toDomain(): PlayersDomainModel {
    val mapMeta : MetaDomainModel
    meta.let {
        mapMeta = MetaDomainModel(meta?.totalPages, meta?.currentPage, meta?.nextPage, meta?.perPage, meta?.totalCount)
    }

    val mapData : MutableList<DataDomainModel> = mutableListOf()
    data.let {
        for(item in data){
            val mapTeam : TeamDomainModel = TeamDomainModel(item.team?.id, item.team?.abbreviation, item.team?.city, item.team?.conference, item.team?.division, item.team?.fullName, item.team?.name)
            mapData.add(DataDomainModel(item.id, item.firstName, item.heightFeet, item.heightInches, item.lastName, item.position, mapTeam, item.weightPounds))
        }
    }

    return PlayersDomainModel(mapData, mapMeta)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why simple data class suppose to have a map method.

Instead of mapping:

```
return response.map { it.toDomain() }
```

just use `toDomain()` on the response:

```
return response.toDomain()
```

Comment: I had seen people doing like this before, but your comment save my time. Thank you

Comment: How I can convert a list of object to another with the same extension functions. Something like:  fun MutableList<DataEntity>.toDomain() : MutableList<DataDomainModel> {
...
}

Comment: In this case, you can use the map method from Kotlin Collections. Something like this: exampleList.map { it.toDomain() }